# Apache <Directory> blocks

Tags: apache, security, directory, httpd.conf

I'm trying to make it so that the outside world can't access a specific section of my website. What I did was:

```
<Directory /Library/WebServer/.../secrets/>
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 10.0.1.18
</Directory>
```

(10.0.1.18 is my computer's internal IP) That seemed to work for the root folder, but not for subfolders. So I tried secrets/* in the directory block, but that disabled everything. Anyone could access the secrets folder.

How would I make the directory block apply to subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory):

> `<Directory> and </Directory>` are used to enclose a group of directives
>   that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that
>   directory, and the files within the respective directories.

So if you omit the trailing slash then this should work:

```
<Directory /Library/WebServer/.../secrets>
```

secrets/* means subdirectories and files below the secrets directory, not the directory itself.

Comment: Well, that worked. But it also locked me out. I still have the 10.0.1.18 ip address... Could it be that the secrets folder is a web app? (phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Can you get to the phpMyAdmin login screen or can't you even see that?

Comment: No, I can't see that. I just get the "access forbidden" page.